# HighDPI Mode Error for Visual Basic Project using .NET 5

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-5, target-framework

Getting an error in my Error List: 'Forms' is not a member of 'Windows'.
This error occurs when I add a Target Framework Moniker (TFM).

Before (no error)
`<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`

After (error occurs)
`<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>`

This is per instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance

The goal behind doing this is to gain access to the "Windows.Storage.ApplicationData" API.

My project is a Windows Forms App (Visual Basic | Windows | Desktop)

A temporary work-around is to comment out the "Windows.Forms.Application..." line. But this obviously affects the HighDPIMode.

```
        Dim eventArgs = New ApplyHighDpiModeEventArgs(
            If(
               _highDpiMode Is Nothing,
               HighDpiMode.SystemAware,
               _highDpiMode.Value))

            RaiseEvent ApplyHighDpiMode(Me, eventArgs)

            **Windows.Forms.Application.SetHighDpiMode(eventArgs.HighDpiMode)**

            Return MyBase.OnInitialize(commandLineArgs)
        End Function
```

The error can be easily reproduced by creating a new project using Windows Forms App and targeting .NET 5. When the project opens up, click on the App in Solution, it should open a Project Sdk window. Change the TFM to `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>` and build the project.

Can anyone provide assistance or direction as to how to solve the error? But still maintain having access to the WinRT APIs and High DPI Mode.

Thanks!

Comment: You're on the bleeding edge of agile here, this isn't adequately debugged yet.  Use Help > Send Feedback to let them know you care.

Comment: Copy that, I have submitted the feedback. Much appreciated.